# Which namaz I can done to forgiveness

Tags: practical-islam

Please tell me that which namaz is required to forgiveness.beacause in my mind all time negative thought is produced about my family then I ask Allah this thought is accepted or not by using yes and no paper by putting hand on kuran sharif.but at that time I felt so guilty because I put on hand on kuran and ask allah.but in my loneliness i can't know what I am done i.e.puttind hand on kuran and ask Allah this thing make me so guilty ..and always produce the fear about future .my family is most important for me .and I getting fear about them that what happen to my family in future.beacuse I put hand on kuran and ask to allah.how I get forgiveness by Allah .please tell me.sometime I feel sucide thought,beacause in my mind thought is produced that because my negative thought and put hand on kuran then my family member get punished by Allah...please tell me that which namaz give me forgiveness by Allah and accepted my dua 100percentaage.

Comment: There's no way to deal with Allah in a manner that you may find a formulation or worship you do once and be forgiven it is a process of obeying Allah and trying to avoid disobeying Him and true repentance is the key.

Answer (score 0):

May Allah forgive us All.
According to your question & explanation What i understand that you got problem which everyone of us have. While praying, all of us gets different things in our mind, some gets family, some gets tensions etc but still we pray and still show our attendance in front of Allah. We are not angels, We are Humans.
As Allah says in Quran:

> إِنَّمَا أَمْوَالُكُمْ وَأَوْلَادُكُمْ فِتْنَةٌ ۚ وَاللَّهُ عِندَهُ أَجْرٌ عَظِيمٌ - 64:15
>
> Your wealth and your children are but a trial, and Allah has with Him
> a great reward.
>
> Tumhara Maal Aur Tumhari Aulaad to Aazmaish Hai,
> Aur ALLAH Kay Haan Bara Ajar Hai.

So if you are thinking about family then its natural as Allah Himself says that its trial.

As far as the matter related to paper which you wrote and put in the Quran then I think its just a small mistake u did because you were alone. You just tried to Ask Allah but the way you choose was **wrong**. Just Seek Tauba for the next time. He must Forgive you.
Quran says:

> وَلَقَدْ خَلَقْنَا الْإِنسَانَ وَنَعْلَمُ مَا تُوَسْوِسُ بِهِ نَفْسُهُ ۖ وَنَحْنُ أَقْرَبُ إِلَيْهِ مِنْ حَبْلِ الْوَرِيدِ - 50:16
>
> And certainly We created man, and We know what his mind suggests to him, and We are nearer to him than his life-vein.

Allah is nearer to you than your life vein. so you dont need to put paper or You dont need the special prayer,but real tauba from the heart. Even u just pray 2 Nafil but pray from the core of your heart .He must listen you. InshAllah.
May Allah forgive us all.